# Dois CLICKs JavaScript em um só lugar, pode um cancelar o outro?

Tags: javascript, click

Estou com um probleminha e gostaria, por gentileza, de contar com a ajuda de vocês.
Na IMAGEM 1: eu tenho um click ($('.open-Box').click(function (openBox) {) na linha 170, mas dentro desta linha eu tenho outro click ($('.arq-folder').click(function (arqfolder) {) na linha 173.

Se eu clicar em qualquer área da linha da IMAGEM 2 onde indico com uma seta vermelha o click da class "open-Box" executa, isto está OK, o "probleminha" é que quando clico no ícone azul (folder) para executar o click da class "arq-folder", o click da class "open-box" também executa, mas isso não poderia acontecer! Parece impossível, pois a class "arq-folder" é de uma div que está dentro da div com a class "open-box". Minha pergunta é: Se é possível o click class "arq-folder", tipo cancelar o click da class "open-box"?
Tô me acabando de tentar e tentar... aff.
[image: Imagem vale mais que mil palavras (rs)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode chamar o método `stopPropagation` no evento.

Imagine que quando você clica em algum elemento da sua página, um evento é criado. Esse evento de click é gerado no elemento que você clicou, e então é elevado ao elemento pai dele, e depois elevado ao elemento pai do pai, e assim suscetivamente até chegar na raiz do seu DOM.

Você adicionou um `eventListener` nos elementos `arq-folder` e `open-Box`, isso significa que existe um componente escutando eventos nesses elementos, quando um evento de clique passa por esses elementos, a função que você definiu nesses listeners é invocada.

Se você não quer que o evento capturado no `arq-folder` seja capturado no `open-Box`, basta chamar o método `stopPropagation` nesse evento, e ele não será mais elevado aos elementos pais. Como o evento não será elevado até o `open-Box`, a função desse elemento não será ativada. Exemplo (clique na linha da tabela):

```js
$('.open-Box').click(e => {
  console.clear()
  console.log('Ativou o evento do "open-Box"')

})

$('.arq-folder').click(e => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.clear()
  console.log('Ativou somente o evento do "arq-folder"')
})
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>S</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>Cliente</th>
    <th>Descrição do produto</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="open-Box">
    <td></td>
    <td class="arq-folder"></td>
    <td>João Batista de Carvalho Azevedo</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: SEN-SA-CI-O-NAL cara! demais... muito obrigado... mas tinha um conflito e eu tive que retirar o script da página (include do php) e levar para uma página pai e fiz assim: <div class='col1 emCenter' onclick='ativa("<?php echo $eidneg; ?>");' data='<?php echo $eidneg; ?>' style='width:30px;'> e no javascript: function ativa(valor) {... aff aff cof cof... O stopPropagation agora não quer funfar!!! ai ai (obs: vou retirar o data='<?php echo $eidneg; ?>', pois ainda estou testando muitas coisas...)

Comment: Cara... demais... saca só o que resolveria o caso: onclick='event.stopPropagation(); ativa("<?php echo $eidneg; ?>");' O que achou Dr. Mistério (vulgo user140828)? Você aprova isso? Achou legal? Resolveu! Qual sua opinião? Obrigado irmão!

Comment: @Infonet, eu não tenho ideia do que está acontecendo nesse código que você postou nos comentários. O código está incompleto, e eu não sei o contexto dele. Seria melhor se você editasse a sua pergunta, ou até fazer uma nova, já que aparentemente agora o problema é outro.

Comment: Cara! Tá de boassa! Você já respondeu a pergunta... blz... nota 11 procê! Deixa assim... Eu só tenho que agradecer a gentileza que vc concedeu em responder prontamente à minha pergunta. Estou agradecidíssimo! Deus te ilumine.

Comment: Depois de ler muito sobre a solução: onclick='event.stopPropagation(); ativa("<?php echo $eidneg; ?>");' _ percebi que é funcional e utilizado sem restrição, logo, resolvi o problema, já que estou utilizando o "onclick", mas se eu não tivesse alterado meu código, utilizaria _e.stopPropagation()_ para jquery. Meus sinceros agradecimentos ao dr. mistério (rs) @user140828, pela gentileza em me auxiliar. Que Deus o ilumine por isso!